# Authentication using Passport.js on Node.js with React.js frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies, passport.js

I'm a total newbie when it comes to authentication. I am trying to adapt the method used by Colt Steele as part of his [web developer's bootcamp course](https://www.udemy.com/the-web-developer-bootcamp/learn/v4/content)  to my project.

Colt uses Node.js + Express.js + MongoDB, with server-side rendering in ejs. For user authentication, he uses Passport.js.

I'm using Node.js + Express.js + MongoDB with client-side rendering with React.js. I also use React Router. I'm also trying to use Passport to authenticate users.

My problem is that, while I can successfully log in, I still cannot access anything that is behind the login wall. When I make a request to the server to some route that checks if the user is authenticated, the answer is always false.

Here's my auth code.

```
const express = require("express"),
  server = express(),
  path = require("path"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  User = require("./models/User"),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  passport = require("passport"),
  localStrategy = require("passport-local"),
  passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose"),
  expressSession = require("express-session");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/diary");

server.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

//Auth
server.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: "This is pretty damn weird.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  })
);

server.use(passport.initialize());
server.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());    

// Auth login
server.post("/login", function(request, response) {
  passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return response.send(false);
    }
    request.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      checkLogIn(request, response);
      return response.send(true);
    });
  })(request, response);
});

//Auth checkLogIn
function checkLogIn(request, response) {
  if (request.isAuthenticated()) {
    return console.log("authenticated");
  } else {
    return console.log("not authenticated");
  }
}
```

Since I'm using client-side rendering, I cannot use response.redirect to redirect the user anywhere. That is why I use response.send(true) (or false): I use them as flags to tell the React app what to do.

The code above is almost identical to Colt's: he keeps his config of expressSession to a bare minimum and doesn't seem to define his own local strategy or (de-)serialize function. In several tutorials I found, everyone seems to do that, but Colt doesn't and his app works just fine anyway. He doesn't use any MongoStore either, which a lot of other people seem to do.

As you can see I have a checkLogIn function called right after request.logIn that just console.logs whether or not the user is logged in. Right after logging in, it prints true to the screen, i.e. the login is indeed successful.

At this point I should be logged in, but if I try to visit a protected section from my browser, I'll be told that I'm not logged in. For example, I successfully log in as fake user Elmo, and then try to visit /elmo/diary. This takes me to a React component that queries the server on a specific route, this one:

```
//Find all entries of a given user.
router.get("/entries/:userURL", isLoggedIn, (request, response) => {
  console.log("get entries");
  User.findOne(
    { customURL: request.params.userURL },
    { entryIDs: 1 },
    (err, data) => {
      //Get the actual entries.
      Entry.find({ _id: { $in: data.entryIDs } }, (err, entries) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          response.send(entries);
        }
      });
    }
  );
});
```

As you can see, I use a isLoggedIn middleware, which looks like this:

```
//Auth isLoggedIn
function isLoggedIn(request, response, next) {
  console.log(request);
  if (request.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("logged in");
    return next();
  }
  console.log("not logged in");
  return (function() {
    response.send(false);
  })();
}
```

So the route above should return the data if I'm logged in as Elmo. However, whether I'm logged in or not, the middleware will always return false.

I checked my cookies for localhost, where the app is running, and there is just one, with a token-looking value (s%3Ak0SZJ97eJkPjqjE6jC-azn7y3ztK2UMw.fYOfM9324JUIeUDGvh26swEWwMf3j3HDUmh9WubNF%2B8), so I guess Passport is creating the session and storing it in the cookie successfully.

To be honest, I'm not sure how this system works for Colt either, as his front end doesn't seem to send back any token/data for the back-end to check, and my (admittedly limited) understanding was that this is how it should be.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For the client side routing, are you using react-router or express?

Comment: @Dream_Cap react-router.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'login wall' I'm assuming you want to get to a protected route/component. I believe you would need a protected route with react-router like this:

```
 //Placed near your other react router routes, pass the logged in state to this route
  <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} loggedIn={loggedIn} />
```

And then the private route would look like this:

```
 //If auth'd, redirect to the component you want, if not then redirect to login
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, loggedIn }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      loggedIn ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
        />
      )
    )}
  />
);
```

As for letting your route know about if you're logged in, I think you'd  need to store express's auth response in your local React Component state or in Redux(I recently did this in my blog project [here](https://github.com/capozzic1/react-blog). It would be located in your redux store(state) because then you could access it from multiple views/components when it's needed. So for example, the logged in status could be retrieved amongst multiple views.

Here's an example of what the routes would look like:

```
const AllRoutes = ({ loggedIn }) => (
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <div>
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} loggedIn={loggedIn} />
       //other routes
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Here is what the Redux portion would look like to pass loggedIn to allRoutes:

```
   //import connect for connecting the component into redux's store(state)
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//map redux's store to props so the component can access it (this is how loggedIn can get passed in)
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loggedIn: state.signup.loggedIn,
});
 //wraps the component in Redux's store(state)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AllRoutes);
```

Comment: How does the value of loggedIn get passed to AllRoutes when you log in?

Comment: I updated the answer to include more info about that

Comment: Did this answer help or no?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. I'm now following a Udemy course saying that react doesn't need to be involved at all, because the browser will automatically attach the authentication cookie to every http request. Indeed, I don't really need protected routes but only authentication to decide whether or not a user can be shown certain data. Sorry if my phrasing was confusing. In any case, thanks for your help!